# How to scrape text from this webpage?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, python-3.7

I'm trying to **scrape** this HTML title

```
<h2 id="p89" data-pid="89"><span id="page77" class="pageNum" data-no="77" data-before-text="77"></span>Tuesday, July&nbsp;30</h2>
```

from this website: https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/h/r1/lp-e

My code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = requests.get('https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/h/r1/lp-e').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'lxml')

textodiario = soup.find('header')

dia = textodiario.h2.text
print(dia)
```

It should returns me today's day but it returns me a passed day: `Wednesday, July 24`

Comment: The page is getting loaded asynchronously and the date is getting changed dynamically, replacing the existing value.

Comment: So... It's not possible to scrap this date?

Comment: How did you arrive at that page? Through a search?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment I don't have a PC to test, please double check for possible errors.

You need the [chromedriver for your platform too](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads), put it in the same folder of the script.

My idea would be to use selenium to get the HTML and then parse it:

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

url = "https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/h/r1/lp-e"
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
page = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
textodiario = soup.find('header')
dia = textodiario.h2.text
print(dia)
```

Answer (score 0):

The data is getting loaded asynchronously and the contents of the div are being changed. What you need is a selenium web driver to act alongside bs4.
[image]

Comment: Thanks! How can I scrap this with selenium?

Comment: That's an entirely different and broad question out of SO scope. We aren't here to do your homework right? Here's a good start : https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/

Answer (score 0):

I actually tried your code, and there's definitely something wrong with how the website/the code is grabbing data. Because when I pipe the entirety of the URL text to a grep with July, it gives:

```
Wednesday, July 24
<h2 id="p71" data-pid="71"><span id="page75" class="pageNum" data-no="75" data-before-text="75"></span>Wednesday, July 24</h2>
<h2 id="p74" data-pid="74">Thursday, July 25</h2>
<h2 id="p77" data-pid="77">Friday, July 26</h2>
```

If I had to take a guess, the fact that they're keeping multiple dates under h2 *probably* doesn't help, but I have almost zero experience in web scraping. And if you notice, July 30th isn't even in there, meaning that somewhere along the line your data is getting weird (as LazyCoder points out).

Hope that Selenium fixes your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `NetWork` Tab and you will get the link.

```
https://wol.jw.org/wol/dt/r1/lp-e/2019/7/30
```

Here is the code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agent':
        'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.106 Safari/537.36'}
session = requests.Session()
response = session.get('https://wol.jw.org/wol/dt/r1/lp-e/2019/7/30',headers=headers)
result=response.json()
data=result['items'][0]['content']
soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
print(soup.select_one('h2').text)
```

Output:

```
Tuesday, July 30
```